# RGL package for R compile error

Tags: r, rgl

Attempting to compile rgl for r on arch linux x86_64. I copied just the error portion of the installation. This has occurred after I recently updated R. Any idea how to solve this?

```
g++ -I/usr/include/R/ -DNDEBUG -DHAVE_PNG_H -I/usr/include/libpng16 -DHAVE_FREETYPE -Iext/ftgl -I/usr/include/freetype2 -Iext -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c init.cpp -o init.o
In file included from /usr/include/freetype2/freetype.h:33:0,
             from ext/ftgl/FTGL/ftgl.h:33,
             from glgui.h:12,
             from gui.h:10,
             from rglview.h:11,
             from Device.h:11,
             from DeviceManager.h:9,
             from init.cpp:6:
init.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* rgl::rgl_init(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)’:
/usr/include/freetype2/config/ftconfig.h:369:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘__typeof__’
 #define TYPEOF( type )  (__typeof__ (type))
                      ^
init.cpp:58:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘TYPEOF’
   else if ( TYPEOF(initValue) == EXTPTRSXP ) {
         ^
/usr/include/freetype2/config/ftconfig.h:369:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__typeof__’
 #define TYPEOF( type )  (__typeof__ (type))
                      ^
init.cpp:58:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘TYPEOF’
   else if ( TYPEOF(initValue) == EXTPTRSXP ) {
         ^
init.cpp:61:3: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘else’
   else if ( !isNull(initValue) )
   ^
/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:143: recipe for target 'init.o' failed
make: *** [init.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with freetype2 2.6. Downgrading to freetype2 2.5 allows rgl to compile properly.

For archlinux you can just run pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/freetype2-2.5.5-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz to downgrade to the older package.

Comment: What about if you haven't previously installed freetype 2 2.5? Cheers.

Comment: I forced a downgrade using pacman -Udd. Still getting same error.

Answer (score 4):

Freetype is optional. Disabling it is the least hassles solution.

install.packages("rgl", repo="http://cran.r-project.org", configure.args="--disable-ftgl")

Answer (score 3):

For others who come looking I solved this on ubuntu by installing `libfreetype6-dev`

Comment: Before install rgl:

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libmagick++-dev libfreetype6-dev`

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the binary from the repos:

   sudo apt-get build-dep r-cran-rgl

or

2. Install OpenGL before building `rgl` from source.

Comment: Yeah OpenGL is installed before compiling. The error is associated with freetype. Also, archlinux doesnt use apt for repositories.

Comment: yaourt -S r-cran-rgl for archlinux, but this just builds it from source rather than using a binary. Also, it's a disowned AUR package meaning it's outdated. It's better to compile from within R using install.packages("rgl") than the AUR. Either way the error remains the same. The issue is not associated with OpenGL at all.